# How to solve execution failed due to a certain reason?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have been executing my app in Android Studio, but the task is failed with an error message 'Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 1277548 found in cache 'C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.'

Please someone help me out

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the file-access.bin in path C:\Users.gradle\caches\journal-1. After deleting it, I restarted Android Studio and rebuilt the project.